# Prevent auto-stretch IK in Rigify with Blender 2.8

Tags: rigify

I am looking for the auto-stretch IK feature in Rigify for Blender 2.8 in order to de-activate it (set it to zero).
This feature was under Rig Main Property toolbox in the previous version of Blender (see capture below).

[image: Auto strech IK Blender 2.7x]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

OK so I guess I looked everywere exept were it was :/ Turns out it was under the Item tab.

However, setting IK_Strech to zero didn't fix the problem...

[image: Not working]

Any input appreciated.